# How to set LastWriteTime property of a file?

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I would like to change the creation date of the files that I generate with this script :

```
$clientname = Read-Host "Enter the client name"
$path = Read-Host "Enter the complete path of .bak files"

$time = "01-00-00"
$space = " "


for ($i = 0; $i -lt 7;$i++)
{

$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1-$i).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') 

New-Item -ItemType file $path$clientname$space$date$space$time.bak

}
```

So it gives me theses files :

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                          
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                          
-a---        16/08/2013     16:55          0 client 2013-08-15 01-00-00.bak                                  
-a---        16/08/2013     16:55          0 client 2013-08-14 01-00-00.bak                                  
-a---        16/08/2013     16:55          0 client 2013-08-13 01-00-00.bak                                  
-a---        16/08/2013     16:55          0 client 2013-08-12 01-00-00.bak                                  
-a---        16/08/2013     16:55          0 client 2013-08-11 01-00-00.bak                                  
-a---        16/08/2013     16:55          0 client 2013-08-10 01-00-00.bak                                  
-a---        16/08/2013     16:55          0 client 2013-08-09 01-00-00.bak
```

I want to modify the LastWriteTime property of each files, I want it to be the same as the date in the file name.

Example for this file `"client 2013-08-15 01-00-00.bak"` the LastWriteTime will be `"15/08/2013 01:00"`

I'm stuck and I do not how can we do that

Thank you

Comment: FYI http://pscx.codeplex.com has a Set-FileTime command (alias touch) that is quite handy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not tested, but try this in your loop after you call New-Item:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem $path$clientname$space$date$space$time.bak
$file.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1-$i)
```

If you want to see a full listing of things you can do with FileInfo objects, try calling `$file | gm` in your powershell console. You could also view the [docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 7;$i++)
{
     $date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1-$i)
     $filedate = $date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') 
     $file = New-Item -ItemType File $path$clientname$space$filedate$space$time.bak
     $file.LastWriteTime = $date
}
```