# Windows-Script: Change LastChanged Date from Files in Directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I have in a directory many Files (extension .png, .jpg, .mov and .mp4).
I want to 'overwrite' the lastChanged Date from this Files by the title.

The Files are named like:

```
IMG_20171222_212535.jpg
IMG_20170130_020006.png
IMG_20170101_000005.mp4
```

After the Script was running i want to have the lastChanged dates as the date and time in the title:

```
IMG_20171222_212535.jpg --> LastChange: 22 Dec 2017, 21:25:35
IMG_20170130_020006.png --> LastChange: 30 Jan 2017, 02:00:06
```

Thank you for your help[image]

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a free script writing service. See also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276452/how-to-set-lastwritetime-property-of-a-file

Comment: Read the help for the `FOR` command.  The very last section talks about the command modifiers. The `%~tI` modifier expands to the date and time of the file.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you wish to modify a file today to show a last modified date which isn't today!